# ASP.NET app works on Cassini but not in IIS on xp?

Tags: asp.net, iis

App works fine in IIS on Windows 7 on my dev machine.  Trying to debug on a client machine running XP and VS2008 and the app works ok running on Cassini, however when I select IIS I am getting a 403 forbidden error.  Anonymous access is switched on in ISS.  Can anyone help work out why it won't work in IIS?

Comment: I've added Network Service and the anonymous user account to the folder and contents and still getting a 403 :(

Comment: hi, i got the same problem, where you able to fix it? Please let me know thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to add permission to this folder for *Network Service* user, may be help.

Answer (score 0):

check that it isn't set to impersonate. Usually you just have to give permissions to Network Service (as mentioned by @loviji), but depending on your application and your computer configuration you may need to give permissions to the account that is configured for anonymous users in IIS.